# Apache - HTaccess: Redirect .\testvid to .\videos\testvid - With testvid being a variable

Tags: apache, .htaccess, variables, redirect

I am trying to redirect

`.\testvid` to `.\videos\testvid`

using htaccess

but i am also doing it for 100s of folders sich as:

`.\testvid2` to `.\videos\testvid2`

`.\testvid3` to `.\videos\testvid3`

`.\testvid4` to `.\videos\testvid4`

can i do:

`.\{SET_VARIABLE}` to `.\videos\{VARIABLE HERE}`

I can currently do it with an static entry

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/testvid http://domain_here.com/New_fodler/testvid
```

but i would love to set it with a variable

Thanks!

Comment: **SOLUTION:** 'RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$/video.htm /videos/$1/video.htm [R=301,L]'

Answer (score 0):

I think you have `\` instead of `/` in your examples.

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /videos/$1 [L,R=301]
```